# Blender part in dishwasher, poisonous?

Tags: blender

I washed a part that should not be washed in the washing machine. Now the metal part is no longer shiny and gives off an oily substance. How dangerous can this be? In terms of toxins and to the other things in the dishwasher? I did a quick wash without soap after I found out.

Edit:
Awaiting answer from tech support, they might have to ask the factory. I think its strange that the inside of the cog is covered in oil, if its from the part above. There is no visible oil on anything else, even on the plastic or the blades. I think it may be a coating on the cog, reacting to water and soap, may be completely wrong here.

[image: close-up of blender coupling] [image: wider shot showing grease on paper towel]

Comment: Does that surface even come in contact with the food?

Comment: No, i will order a new part anyway, more concerned about the dishwasher and the plates cups etc washed together with it. I probably should have been more clear : )

Answer (score 6):

It seems that oil has been driven out of the bearings.

For getting rid of oil contamination, soap is actually very useful. One or two empty runs should certainly get rid of what is left in the dishwasher itself, even if the oil is not food grade - otherwise, everyone running a dishwasher professionally would have to be worried about someone having eg touched a cup or plate with motor oil on his fingers.

Check if the bearing still runs decently; it might be best to take the bearing apart and re-grease it (this one looks like it is designed to be taken apart) - check whether you can find a repair manual and/or advice from the manufacturer on what grease should be used here.

If you use any non-approved type of grease, pay heightened attention when using the blender - any strange noises, smoke, slowing down... mean turn it off now.

Comment: I am unshure if its bearing oil, its equally oily inside the cog, the bearing oil should come from the other side, away from where the picture is taken, if i understand​ correctly. I think its a coating on the cog that should not come in contact with water, i dont know, the tech support sendt my case higher up, awaiting answer from them, may take time if the have to ask the factory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will run it with the same dishes and soap one more time. Most people i have talked to seemed to think its no problem.  The tech support also said they probably dont have anything that would be too poisonous in a blender, even if that part never would come in contact with the food. If its bearing oil, it certainly makes sense it would be as non-poisonous as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you relube it if you can, if their support can recommend a lube. A bearing suddenly seizing in a blender could end messy.